# onchange must remove value from counter it is storing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

i am creating a voucher, for an Management Program, i have an input field which counts value and add in the last  colum, as sum of debits and credits in all rows for that i am using counters to track sum, i am using onchange or onblur click event, it works well it counts wih increase in rows, but when i try to remove the value from input it still couns i counter

here is the code

```
var credit_counter = 0;
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="credit[]"]', function () {
  idName = $(this).attr('id');
  id = idName.substring(6, idName.length);
  var value = $(this).val();
  credit_counter = credit_counter + Number(value);
  var credit_balance = $("#get_credit").val(credit_counter)
});

var debit_counter = 0;
var total_balance = 0;

$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="debit[]"]', function () {
  idName = $(this).attr('id');
  id = idName.substring(6, idName.length);
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#credit" + id).val(value)
  debit_counter = debit_counter + Number(value);
  var debit_balance = $("#get_debit").val(debit_counter);
});
```

I want to remove the value in case I erase value from input field thanks

Comment: please post the html markup for your view and we will be of more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example which achieves what you are looking to do (warning: no styling has been added so it is ugly). You can copy and paste this into a `.html` file and open it in with the web browser of your choice to see it in action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input placeholder="credit field 1" type="text" name="credit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="credit field 2" type="text" name="credit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="credit field 3" type="text" name="credit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="credit field 4" type="text" name="credit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="debit field 1" type="text" name="debit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="debit field 2" type="text" name="debit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="debit field 3" type="text" name="debit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="debit field 4"type="text" name="debit" /><br/>
<input placeholder="credit total" id="get_credit" type="text" /><br/>
<input placeholder="debit total" id="get_debit" type="text" /><br/>


<script>
$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="credit"]', function () {
  var total = 0;
  $('input[name="credit"]').each(function( index, element ) {
      if(!isNaN($(this).val())){
        total += Number($(this).val());
      }
      $('#get_credit').val(total);
  });
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input[name="debit"]', function () {
  var total = 0;
  $('input[name="debit"]').each(function( index, element ) {
      if(!isNaN($(this).val())){
        total += Number($(this).val());
      }
      $('#get_debit').val(total);
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your issue is that the way you are keeping track of the total debits and total credits does not allow you to know the values stored in each input individually. The problem that creates is that when a value is removed, there is no way for you to know what to subtract from the total. (Likewise, if someone were to change the value from 3 to 30 then your total would go up by 30 instead of 27).

There is definitely more than one way to fix that however the answer I posted is what I believe to be most simple: On blur of the input, iterate through the appropriate inputs and add them together then assign the total to the appropriate input.

Note I've excluded your logic of acting on the `id`s of the inputs as it is unclear what you're doing with them without further explanation or seeing your view markup. It also seems to be unrelated to the issue you're posting about.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your problem. Can we do like this.

1) Trigger an event on focus.

2) Subtract the focused element value from total.

If user doesn't removed complete value from the input. anyway we are triggering event on blur. So it will take whatever the value remained in the text box and counts that!

Comment: what if the user clicks on the input field (which will trigger the onfocus event) and then clicks out of it without changing the value? then we would have removed a value from the total erroneously.

Comment: @GregH Your answer is perfect!